# How can use an in-memory H2 database when testing my Quarkus application?

Tags: quarkus

I plan to use PostgreSQL as the database for my Quarkus application but I would like the convenience of using H2 in my tests.

Is there a way I can accomplish such a feat?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update 2**

Recent versions of Quarkus can launch H2 automatically in dev and test mode when `quarkus-jdbc-h2` is on the classpath and no URL configuration is provided.
See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#devservices-configuration-free-databases) for more information.

Also, you should favor the datasource "kind" when configuring the driver, instead of pointing to a driver explicitly.

In short:

- Add `io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-h2` as a `test` scoped dependency
- Configure your app this:

  ```
  quarkus.datasource.kind=postgresql
  %test.quarkus.datasource.kind=h2
  # Only set this in the prod profile, otherwise tests won't work
  %prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://mypostgres:5432
  ```

**Update**

As of version `1.13`, Quarkus can launch H2 automatically in dev and test mode when `quarkus-jdbc-h2` is on the classpath and no URL configuration is provided.
See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#devservices-configuration-free-databases) for more information.

**Original answer**

Quarkus provides the [H2DatabaseTestResource](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/0.11.0/test-framework/h2/src/main/java/io/quarkus/test/h2/H2DatabaseTestResource.java) which starts an in memory H2 database as part of the test process.

You will need to add `io.quarkus:quarkus-test-h2` as a `test` scoped dependency and annotate your test with `@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)`.
You will also need to have something like:

```
quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:test
quarkus.datasource.driver=org.h2.Driver
```

in `src/test/resources/application.properties`

In order for the application use PostgreSQL as part of its regular run, `quarkus-jdbc-postgresql` should be a dependency and

```
quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://mypostgres:5432
quarkus.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
```

should be set in `src/main/resources/application.properties`

Comment: I tried to use this approach in my sample, but failed. It reported the connection timeout. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900569/exception-occured-in-test-when-add-hibernate-orm-panache-in-quarkus

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below configurations in the application.properties file to use h2 database

```
    quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:default
    quarkus.datasource.driver=org.h2.Driver
    quarkus.datasource.username=admin
    quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
```