# Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:h2:mem:default in Quarkus application

Tags: java, testing, configuration, h2, quarkus

### My problem

I'd like to use a PostgreSQL database for development and a H2 Database for testing.

My application works well with my PostgreSQL DB. However, the test part with H2 gets me the following error when I launch my resource tests:

```java
Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:h2:mem:default
```

I have the following extensions for H2 inside my pom.xml :

- quarkus-test-h2 (scope test)
- quarkus-jdbc-h2

My conf files are below.

I'll take any advice. Thanks

### An example of class that raises the error

```java
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)
class ShopResourceTest {
    KeycloakTestClient keycloakTestClient = new KeycloakTestClient();

    @Test
    void nominalCreateShop() {
        CreateShopDto createShopDto = new CreateShopDto(
                "My Super shop!!",
                "bha",
                null
        );
        Response response = given().auth().oauth2(keycloakTestClient.getAccessToken("john")).contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(createShopDto).when().post("/shops").then().statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED).extract().response();
        ShopDto shopDto = response.as(ShopDto.class);
        assertEquals(shopDto.name(), createShopDto.name());
        assertEquals(shopDto.prefix(), createShopDto.prefix());
        assertNotNull(shopDto.createdOn());
        assertNotNull(shopDto.openedOn());
        assertNull(shopDto.archivedOn());
    }
}
```

### My application.properties

```bash
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=postgres
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.physical-naming-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true

%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:default
%test.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
%test.quarkus.datasource.username=sa
%test.quarkus.datasource.password=
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.physical-naming-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
```

### My pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxxxx</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.6.8</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-authorization</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-keycloak-server</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <formats>
            <format>
              <includes>
                <include>.gitattributes</include>
                <include>.gitignore</include>
              </includes>
              <trimTrailingWhitespace />
              <endWithNewline />
              <indent>
                <tabs>true</tabs>
                <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
              </indent>
            </format>
          </formats>
          <java>
            <cleanthat />
            <googleJavaFormat>
              <version>1.18.1</version>
              <style>GOOGLE</style>
              <reflowLongStrings>true</reflowLongStrings>
              <formatJavadoc>false</formatJavadoc>
            </googleJavaFormat>
            <indent>
              <tabs>true</tabs>
              <spacesPerTab>2</spacesPerTab>
            </indent>
            <importOrder />
            <removeUnusedImports />
            <licenseHeader>
              <content>/* (C)$YEAR */</content>
            </licenseHeader>
          </java>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

### The detailed error log

The following message is obtained when running tests and reaching the above test class:

```bash
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:638)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.run(StartupActionImpl.java:285)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:252)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:605)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:655)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: <default>] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig.startAll(JPAConfig.java:78)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder.startAllPersistenceUnits(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits1868654632.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits1868654632.deploy(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: <default>] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.persistenceException(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:126)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:86)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:74)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:156)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:h2:mem:default] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.getIsolatedConnection(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlString(Helper.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.applySqlStrings(Helper.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropTables(SchemaDropperImpl.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropConstraintsTablesSequences(SchemaDropperImpl.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.observers.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:21)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.build(FastBootEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:84)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:h2:mem:default
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.connectionSetup(ConnectionFactory.java:242)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:226)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:536)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:517)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more


org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: Boot failed


    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:640)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

### I've already tried...

- to use my PostgreSQL DB for both development and testing, it works well.
- to restart my IDE (IntelliJ)
- what has been done here: [How can use an in-memory H2 database when testing my Quarkus application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063778/how-can-use-an-in-memory-h2-database-when-testing-my-quarkus-application)

### I expect...

a solution to my problem or some advice from experienced people

Thank you!

Comment: Just for the record, the `io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-h2` dependency specified as compile scope instead of test. Do you really need to use an in-memory database driver in production? I assume it is just a mistake.

Comment: This is totally a mistake! Thanks for notifying it. I changed it to the scope of test. However it doesn't seem to impact my initial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll drop the obligatory comment: "you should test on an environment as similar to prod as possible, so testing on PostgreSQL would be better". As it's relatively easy with Quarkus' [Dev Services](https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services), you might want to give that a try.

If you really want to use H2... I'm not entirely sure this caused your problem, but configuring the driver/dialect is not recommended in recent versions of Quarkus, as it's generally unnecessary and can lead to problems.

Also, you don't need to specify the H2 JDBC URL as Quarkus should start a H2 database on this own.

Try removing `@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)` from your test class and replacing the config with this:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
# This needs to be scoped to prod so that it doesn't interfere with tests
%prod.quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
%prod.quarkus.datasource.password=postgres
%prod.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db
# Do not configure the datasource driver explicitly!

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.physical-naming-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true

# This is all you should need for tests
%test.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
# Do not configure the datasource driver explicitly!
```

If this doesn't work, I'd suggest providing a reproducer.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! I really appreciated.

Since I posted this question, I explored a bit more this topic and finally took the decision to use a single environment for testing and completely switched to PostgreSQL. 

As you also suggested it and it allowed me to get unstuck, I'm going to accept your answer. Have a nice day!